Bootstrap dropdown submenu in Rails
I am trying to get a multi-level drop down working in my application as the 1 level  navigation is not fit for future requirments. The application was initially programmed by external devs and have basically little clue about front-end so it means "try and error" approach.
I read and tried to apply https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/dropdown-multilevel/# but on click on a new navigation item which is supposed to open a new submenu with some dummy entries the menu is dissappearing in total instead of showing the submenu with the dummy entries.
The application is written in Ruby on Rails but non Ruby on Rails answers hopefully can be translated by me.
The code of the header view partial with the 1-level-navigation working today:
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col header_custom">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-dark bg-dark py-0 shadow-sm fixed-top custom-navbar">
        <div>
          <%= image_tag "logo.png", style: 'width:25px;'%>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= link_to 'fitaf - fury in the accounting factory', root_path, class: 'navbar-brand font-weight-bold mr-auto logo-name' %>
          <% if current_user.present? && current_user.accounting_company.present?%>
            <br>
            <p class="white-text"><%= header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :accounting_for, company_name: current_user.accounting_company.name_and_type) %> </p>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-toggler order-md-1 menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarContent" aria-controls="navbars" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse order-sm-12 order-lg-1" id="navbarContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <% if current_user.present? %>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :navigation), 'javascript:void(0)',class: 'nav-link dropdown-toggle font-weight-bold text-uppercase top-menu', id: 'management', data: {toggle: 'dropdown'}, aria: {haspopup: 'true', expanded: 'false'} %>
                <div class="dropdown-menu border-0 p-0 m-0 w-100" aria-labelledby="#management">
                  <div class="container-fluid justify-content-start justify-content-lg-end">
                    <div class="row bg-dark text-light rounded-0 m-0 shadow-sm w-100">
                      <div class="col-12 px-0">
                        <div class="pt-2 pb-4 pl-sm-0 pl-lg-4 pr-0">
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="">
                              <ul class="">
                                <% if current_user.fitaf_employee? %>
                                  <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                    <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :user), admin_users_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                    <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :company), admin_companies_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                    <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :accounting_framework), admin_accounting_frameworks_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                  <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :company_type), admin_company_types_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                  </li>
                                  <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                    <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :country), admin_countries_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                  </li>
                                <% elsif current_user.accounting_company.present? %>
                                  <% company = current_user.accounting_company %>
                                  <% if company.present? %>
                                    <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                      <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :home), home_company_path(company), class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                      <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :company_in_invoice), home_company_in_invoices_path(company), class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                      <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :company_out_invoice), home_company_out_invoices_path(company), class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                      <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :company_in_payment), home_company_in_payments_path(company), class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                      <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :company_out_payment), home_company_out_payments_path(company), class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                    </li>
                                    <% end %>
                                  <% end %>
                                  <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                    <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :all_companies), home_companies_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                  </li>
                              </ul>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :edit_profile), edit_user_registration_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 top-menu' %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :logout), logout_path, method: :delete, class: 'nav-link pb-0 top-menu' %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item switch-languages">
                <%= link_to Language.display_selection(I18n.locale), "javascript: void()", class: "nav-link pb-0 top-menu language-selected" %>
                <div class="language-dropdown">
                  <% Language.menu_options(I18n.locale).each do |language, locale| %>
                    <% if Language.hide_selected_locale(locale) %>
                      <div class="language-item">
                        <%= image_tag("flags/#{flag_selector(locale)}.png") %><br>
                        <%= link_to language, switch_language_path(locale: locale, redirect_path: request.fullpath), method: :post %>
                      </div>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </li>
            <% else %>
              <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:not_logged_in, :login), login_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:not_logged_in, :registration), register_path, class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item d-xl-inline-block switch-languages">
                <%= link_to Language.display_selection(I18n.locale), "javascript: void()", class: "nav-link pb-0 menu-item language-selected" %>
                <div class="language-dropdown">
                  <% Language.menu_options(I18n.locale).each do |language, locale| %>
                    <% if I18n.locale != locale %>
                      <div class="language-item">
                        <%= link_to language, switch_language_path(locale: locale, redirect_path: request.fullpath), method: :post %>
                      </div>
                    <% end %>
                  <% end %>
                </div>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

So lets say for example I want to create an invoice submenu with 2 items linking to in_invoices & out_invoices so above navigation it would mean this two items need to be grouped:
                                    <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                      <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :company_in_invoice), home_company_in_invoices_path(company), class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="nav-item d-lg-inline-block">
                                      <%= link_to header_menu_translation(:logged_in, :company_out_invoice), home_company_out_invoices_path(company), class: 'nav-link pb-0 menu-item' %>
                                    </li>

